# How to make "border: 1px solid #72777d" inline

Tags: css, less

I have used "border: 1px solid #f2f2f2" to apply the border for the boxes As shown in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHM4K.png), As I used 1px solid, the border of one box is getting overlap with border of another box, So I want to use inline border using CSS. Any solution? Thanks in advance ^_^.

```
border: 1px solid #f2f2f2
```

Comment: Can you be specific on what element you are applying this styling to?

Comment: Added Image for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: have you tried border-style: inset

Comment: yeah but still the border is overlapping, with the other box.

Comment: Issue is Solved with the below Viira's solution, Thanks, But still wondering as My question got -3 (._.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing:border-box` so that the element won't exceeds its height and width.

```css
.box{
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
        width:50px; 
        height:50px; 
        background:red; 
        float:left;
        }

.box1{ 
    background:green; 
    float:left;  
    width:50px; 
    margin-left:15px;
    height:50px;
   }
 
 .box2{ 
    background:yellow; 
    float:left;  
    width:50px; 
    margin-left:15px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    height:50px;
   }
 
.overall{
      background:#353535;
      height:100vh;
      padding:50px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">

<div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
 <div class="box2">
 </div>
  </div>
```

As you can `.box`, `.box2` and `.box3` has same width and height

By using `box-sizing` property the first box isn't exceeding its limit and it won't overlap the nearby elements

See yellow box it also has the same height, width. Without box-sizing it exceeds its height and width.

Comment: Thanks ^_^ Helped me :-) Issue Solved !